# Como simular o pressionamento da tecla enter no selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou usando selenium e tentei localizar o botão de publicar do instagram, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que meu programa clique nele depois de digitar algo. Já tentei algo como:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]").click()
```

Porém sem respostas, gostaria de saber se simular o 'enter' poderia resolver esse problema. Se sim, como eu poderia simular esta tecla?

Comment: Se você está tentando comentar nas fotos tente o seguinte: ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()``` e veja se funciona

Answer (score 0):

Bem , para dar o enter primeiro voce deve importar `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

esse pacote realiza o pressionamento de todas as teclas especiais incluindo Enter

depois que fez isto, e so mandar a tecla enter para um elemento na pagina:

Exemplo de um script que pesquisa no google clicando enter em vez do botão pesquisar:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys from selenium import webdriver
    
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() driver.get('https://www.google.com.br/') 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys("Enter pressionado")

    # aqui eu pressiono e botao Enter 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

> espero ter resolvio sua duvida abraços